# delay after opening lid display dark until key pressed

Tags: sleep-wake, power-management, nvram

okay so my MBP Mid 2010 was took a little tumble (it was in a felt sleeve which was inside a backpack) today and since has been acting weird.

when i open the lid, the login screen does not come back on automatically, i have push a key, move a finger or two on trackpad and only then does the display get powered

what to do? I am on OSX 10.8.5 and non SSD, 4GB Ram.
Plz help!

Answer (score 1):

Check that `pmset -g hibernatemode` command in Terminal gives you 3 or 0 and not any other value. If it gives you something else, execute `pmset hibernatemode 3` (this is the correct default).

Sometimes these settings go wrong for unknown reason.

Comment: done, it made no difference to the situation. i must add here that the mac runs fine otherwise.